# display last post modified date in genesis child themes

Tags: posts, functions, child-theme, genesis-theme-framework

Since I frequently update posts so it’s crucial for me to display last modified date instead of post published date like following image. Its because I want search engine to display my post last modified date not post published date. Can anyone help me regarding this issue any help would be appreciated.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try using [the_modified_date()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_modified_date) or [the_modified_time()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/the_modified_time), which should display the last updated date.

Comment: i know that since i'm not expert in coding i'm not being able to implement it properly :(

Comment: Add the code you are using to your question.

Answer (score 0):

Genesis displays post date using the shortcode `[post_date]` and also lets you filter the post info..

Try this..

```
add_shortcode('post_updated_date', 'set_last_updated_date');
function set_last_updated_date($atts) {
    if (get_the_modified_time() != get_the_time()){

        return 'Last Updated on ' . the_modified_date('M jS, Y','','',false);
    } else {      
             return 'Published on ' . get_the_time('M jS, Y',false);
    }
}

add_filter( 'genesis_post_info', 'post_info_filter' );
function post_info_filter($post_info) {
    if (is_home()) {
        $post_info = '<span class="home-meta"><time itemprop="dateModified" class="datetime entry-time">[post_updated_date]</time> By<span class="author"> [post_author_posts_link]</span><span class="entry-meta-content hidden-phone"> [post_categories before=" In "]</span></span>';
    } else {
        $post_info = '<span class="entry-meta-content"> [post_author_posts_link]</span><span class="entry-meta-content"> [post_updated_date]</span><span class="entry-meta-content"> [post_categories before=""]</span><span class="entry-meta-content"> [post_comments before=""]</span>';
    }
    return $post_info;
}
```